# css class within a class

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change one class's element in another css class?

Or in particular..

1. The first div with its own class has a css display:none element
2. The second div has a css :hover element
3. I am trying to make the first div visible when hovering over the second div

Tried this, but it does not seem to work:

```
&:hover + .popbox{
display: block; 
}
```

NO JS, has to be pure HTML and CSS

Thanks peeps!

Comment: The CSS shown is most likely from a CSS preprocessor

Comment: You forgot to post your HTML.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That is impossible. The child element (`.popbox`) won't exist in the DOM and can't be interacted with if the parent isn't being displayed (`display:none`). Same goes for the parent element. If it isn't displayed (`display:none`), it can't be interacted.

Comment: Without HTML the question is unclear. But since you're talking about a first and second div and not nested divs remember CSS doesn't have a parent selector

Comment: @SuperDJ CSS has the (:matches)[http://css4.rocks/matches-pseudo-class.php] selector. Which can be used as the (previously) proposed selector to style the parent.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully the snippet will help you..

source : https://codepen.io/bboygaz/pen/FgriI

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.content {
    position :relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carte_button {
    position :absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.carte {
    position :relative;
    top: -3px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    background-color: green;
    width: auto;
    height: 0%;
    margin: auto;
    transition: height 500ms;
}

.carte_button:hover + .carte {
    border-top: none;
    top: 0px;
    height: 300px;
}

.carte:hover {
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="carte_button"></div>
  <div class="carte"></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your two elements with on parent div tag.
This is the code.

```
 .showme{ 
   display: none;
 }
 .showhim:hover .showme{
   display : block;
 }
 .showhim:hover .ok{
   display : none;
 }

<div class="showhim">
     HOVER ME
     <div class="showme">hai</div>
     <div class="ok">ok</div>
</div>
```